# Change background of mapped image hotspot on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemap

I have an image map of 3 polygons.  The actual image hotspots are complex shapes consisting of multiple curves and edges.

```
<img src="/images/map.gif" alt="HTML Map" 
        border="0" usemap="#map"/>

<map name="map">
   <area shape="poly" 
            coords="74,0,113,29,98,72,52,72,38,27"
            href="index.htm" alt="area1" />

   <area shape="poly" 
            coords="22,83,126,125"
            href="index.htm" alt="area2" />

   <area shape="poly" 
            coords="73,168,32"
            href="index.htm" alt="area3" />
</map>
```

I've created a duplicate of map.gif called map_over.gif rendered in a different color.  What I'd like to do is change the area within the clickable hotsposts of map.gif to map_over.gif on mouse hover.  Any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this with CSS or Javascript?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aThis is an easy one.

html:

```
<img src="/images/map.gif" alt="HTML Map" border="0" usemap="#map" id="mappedImage" />
```

css:

```
img#mappedImage:hover {
    background: url("/images/map2.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Should do the trick. You could use the background-image: url("/images/map2.gif") as well - background provides more options at once like background-repeat, background-position etc.

As for any questions about css I can recommend http://www.css4you.de/borderproperty.html as a good reference site with good examples.

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick, had no idea it would be so simple.